# Can't use external JavaScript file in a different directory, only when using WAMP

Tags: permissions, wamp

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863828/relative-path-for-open-method-of-a-xmlhttprequest-object). In WAMP I've got the www directory containing the directories `alpha` and `bravo`. A JavaScript file is in `alpha` and a HTML file that includes the JavaScript is in `bravo`. WAMP seems to have a problem with this, whenever I call a function defined in the JavaScript file it says it's undefined but if I copy the folders to my desktop it works. Is there something going on with permission here?

Comment: If you are talking permissions, the first thing I would do is make sure your .htaccess file is up to scratch, and see if these folders have their own .haccess permissions.

Comment: I never made any `.htaccess` files

Comment: Ah right, without them WAMP runs it's own default modules which might be causing issues. Also are you calling the file through path (like C:\folder\folder\alpha) or relatively (like ..\alpha\js.js) ?

Comment: Relatively. So `../alpha/aScript.js` (at this point I made a test project so the names are bs)

Comment: @Alastor how do I change the default modules?